# My scrapy spider gives an error that I cannot understand

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I just took a course at datacamp and wanted to try out what I had learnt but I ran into errors which I could not understand. 
My code is:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class myspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'my_spider'

    name_loc = '//div[@id="divListView"]//h4/a/text()'
    price_loc = 'div.price > span::text'
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('url=https://www.czone.com.pk/mouse-pakistan-ppt.95.aspx', callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, reponse):
        page1_prices = response.css(myspider.price_loc).extract()
        page1_names = response.xpath(myspider.name_loc).extract()
        for price, name in zip(page1_prices, page1_names):
            mice_names.append(name)
            mice_prices.append(price)
        links = response.css('a.PageNumber::attr(href)').extract()
        for link in links:
            yield response.follow(url=link, callback=self.parse_pages)

    def parse_pages(self, response):
        page_prices = response.css(myspider.price_loc).extract()
        page_names = response.xpath(myspider.name_loc).extract()
        for price, name in zip(page_prices, page_names):
            mice_names.append(name)
            mice_prices.append(price)
mice_names = []
mice_prices = []

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(myspider)
process.start()
print(mice_names)
print(mice_prices)
```

I was trying to scrape names and prices of mice from this website: *https://www.czone.com.pk/mouse-pakistan-ppt.95.aspx*. I attempted to go through all the pages with the information on mice. Even when I comment out the part related to visiting other pages, it still doesn't work and gives the same error.
I tested out the xpath and css locators separately and they seemed to work fine. I even tried comparing with datacamp sample code but still couldn't find the error

The error is:

```
2020-05-21 01:47:50 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.1.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2020-05-21 01:47:50 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.
2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 2.9.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
2020-05-21 01:47:50 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2020-05-21 01:47:50 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{}
2020-05-21 01:47:50 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 2ebba07815410a9b
2020-05-21 01:47:50 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-05-21 01:47:50 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',

 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-05-21 01:47:50 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.32308,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 20, 47, 51, 102851),
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 20, 47, 50, 779771)}
2020-05-21 01:47:51 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
[]
[]
```

I am completely lost. I have no idea what this means. How can I fix this? Please try to guide me through what the parts of the error mean.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the whole output?  I don't see any errors in that block; it looks like regular output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, your error is in start_requests.

```py
def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('url=https://www.czone.com.pk/mouse-pakistan-ppt.95.aspx', callback=self.parse)
```

You put url inside quotes '**url=**https://www.czone.com.pk/mouse-pakistan-ppt.95.aspx'.
What I think you wanted to do is:

```py
def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.czone.com.pk/mouse-pakistan-ppt.95.aspx', callback=self.parse)
```

Your code actually is correct, that's why you don't get an error message. That's one of the worst kinds of bugs to debug...

Comment: So any error related to spiders will be just like any other error in python?

Comment: @Dr.danks Yes, pretty much. Only difference is that Scrapy will continue executing. So for bigger spiders you should write logs to a log file, else the error messages are easily buried in other console output.

Comment: That was one. While reading your answer, I saw that a parameter in the parse function, response had been misspelled.

Comment: @Dr.danks Right, missed that too. The thing is that the parse function never executed since Scrapy only calls your callback, when the request was successful, else you would need to pass a so called errback. That means for example that for status code 404 you could specify a function and pass it as errback to create your own handler with that. If your request would have been successful you would have seen an error message because of your typo in the terminal as well.